# Powershell logging dynamic

Tags: powershell, logging

I would like to log my PowerShell script (version 5.1).

I use the "Write-PSFMessage" function from the "PSFramework" framework (https://psframework.org/).

I don't want to have to manually specify what the command is doing after each command, but would like to pass the system-generated verbose message.

Alternatively, I would also be satisfied if the command line which executes a command is simply passed to the message parameter. But that too should be fully dynamic.

Example (does not work!):

`Write-PSFMessage -Message (($currentline -1).toString()) -Level Verbose`

Does anyone have a good idea?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds like you just want to [enable transcription on the target machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_group_policy_settings?view=powershell-5.1#turn-on-powershell-transcription)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mathias, just use `Start-Transcript .\PSScriptLog.txt` to log all commands and output and then end with `Stop-Transcript` to finalize the log file.